# How to add a relative URL to the web page?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have written a code using `HTML` to practise how to add a relative URL to the web page. But it doesn't work properly.

[image]

Comment: without your file structure there is no way to know why it isnt working for you.

Comment: Sorry, That is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Folder structure for your project.

```
website(Main folder)
   -links.html (html file)
   -gb(Sub folder)
     -currency-converter.html (html file)
```

`links.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>My first website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Let's start creating html links.</p>
  <a href="https://www.ilovepdf.com" target="_blank">Visits to I Love PDF</a>
  <a href="gb/currency-converter.html" target="_blank">Visits to Currency Converter</a>
</body>
</html>
```

`currency-converter.html` file inside the `gb` folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>My second website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Welcome to currency converter page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```